# C# windows Form TextBox Leave event firing infinitely

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, events, event-handling

I am working on C# windows form. I have created a customised textbox using TextBox class.
**At field leave event of TextBox 2 different pop-up windows are being opened**. In some special case I need it. When 2 different pop-us are opening it seems Field leave event is firing twice and it is calling one another recursively.
I have also tried to unregister event before registering event each time using following code

> _fieldLeaveHandler -= value;
>
> _fieldLeaveHandler += value;

But it doesn’t work for me.
I have looked into stack trace but didn’t find any helpful info. How can I check that two Leave event are available in stack?

**Before posting this I have looked into all related question but it doesn't help me.**

Comment: Not a good idea to interfer with focus handling in events like Leave, Enter, GoFocus, LostFocus, Validating, Validated. See [Caution Section on Validating Event Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: you can check `GetInvocationList` of your event `foreach(EventHandler subscriber in _fieldLeaveHandler.GetInvocationList())..`

Comment: A workaround would be to set a "LeaveEventOff" flag being tested in your event handler: If true, no action; If false, set the flag to true, execute the event handler code and set the flag back to false.

Comment: I can't repro this. Can you provide just enough code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I assume that... in your code, you have made textbox validation that restricting to leave the focus of textbox.

Comment: @rene this is not possible to anyone provide their product code to you, they can only provide you scenario to repro.

Comment: @MukeshKumar I'm not asking for the production code, rather not, but for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...